# Why display:inline-block alignment is not as expected

Tags: html, css

Ok, so I was trying to understand the `display:inline-block` property when I got a layout which was not expected.

If I remove the text from first div (i.e `first`), then the alignment is corrected.

```css
div{
  display:inline-block;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div style="background:grey;">first</div>
<div style="background:red;"></div>
```

I want both `<div>` elements to be on the same horizontal level.

I know there are other ways to do this but I really want to know where I went wrong (or what I misunderstood) for this code.

Comment: you must set vertical align for inline-block elements or use flex-boxes to create perfect layotus

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the default property for [`vertical-align`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp) is `baseline`, and you don't specify it in your example. This means that the [inline-block](https://learnlayout.com/inline-block.html) elements will align to their [*baseline*](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2015Mar/0341.html):

> The baseline of an 'inline-block' is the baseline of its last line box in the normal flow, unless it has either no in-flow line boxes or if its 'overflow' property has a computed value other than 'visible', in which case the baseline is the bottom margin edge.

In short, that means that if there is text in an inline-block element, then the element will align to the base of that text. If there is no text, it will align to the bottom margin. So inline-block elements with text in them get pushed *down* compared to those without.

This is corrected by setting a `vertical-align` of `top`, `bottom`, or more preferably, `middle`:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div style="background:grey;">first</div>
<div style="background:red;"></div>
```

One **could** `float` the elements to the `left`, though this works because `float` takes the elements out of the flow context, and treats them as block elements. Applying `float: left` essentially removes `display: inline-block`; you cannot `float` an inline-block element.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div style="background:grey;">first</div>
<div style="background:red;"></div>
```

Gives the same effect as:

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div style="background:grey;">first</div>
<div style="background:red;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend using **FLOATS** . It will make item go out of flow, making the parent container to loose height, for which we need to create some extra css and component.

```
div{
    display:inline-block;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

apply vertical align property. It will be fine. OR you can use flexbox or grid layout. It will be much easier for these things.

Answer (score 0):

```
div{
  display:inline-block;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

always use vertical-align with display: inline: block;

Answer (score -1):

Your going to want to float both of the divs to the left

**try:**

```
div{
  display:inline-block;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  float:left;
}
```

If you want to have space between the two divs add

```
margin-right:1%;
```

Comment: Also, if you add text to the second div it seems to fix both the divs.

Answer (score -1):

You have missed float:left property

```
div{
display:inline-block;
  float:left;
height:100px;
width:100px;
}
```